# SQLite method always crashes my app on onClick

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to create columns in SQL for 3 EditTexts. I thought all the code was good, but it crashes every time I run SAVE via onClick. I have no idea what the errors mean in the logcat. If someone could help out that would be most wonderful. I've spent far too long trying to solve this myself (over an hour).

Logcat:

```
    08-31 02:51:40.241: W/dalvikvm(867): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught         exception (group=0x41465700)
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  ... 11 more
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867): Caused by:    java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at com.mikitz.rogsimple.DamageTracker.save(DamageTracker.java:41)
    08-31 02:51:40.311: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  ... 14 more
```

MainActivity.java:

```
     package com.mikitz.rogsimple;
     import java.util.Random;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
     import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
     import android.view.LayoutInflater;
     import android.view.Menu;
     import android.view.MenuItem;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.ViewGroup;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.TextView;

     public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Random rndNumbers = new Random(); 
int d20    = rndNumbers.nextInt(20) +1; 
Button roll;
TextView display;
ROGDatabaseAdapter ROGHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ROGHelper=new ROGDatabaseAdapter(this);

    roll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.d20);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
roll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
d20    = rndNumbers.nextInt(20) +1; 
                display.setText(" " + d20);
            }
        });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

public void damagetrackerpage (View view)
{
    Intent intent=new Intent (this, DamageTracker.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void charactersheetpage (View view)
{
    Intent intent=new Intent (this, CharacterProfile.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

ROGDatabaseAdapter.java:

```
    package com.mikitz.rogsimple;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;



    public class ROGDatabaseAdapter  {

ROGHelper helper;

public ROGDatabaseAdapter(Context context) 
{
    helper=new ROGHelper(context);
}

public long insertData(String armorhealthchest, String healthchest, String abvchest)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ROGHelper.AHChest, armorhealthchest);
    contentValues.put(ROGHelper.HChest, healthchest);
    contentValues.put(ROGHelper.ABVChest, abvchest);
    long id=db.insert(ROGHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return id; 
}

static class ROGHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="rogdatabase";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME="ARMORSTATS";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=10;
    private static final String UID="_id";
    private static final String AHChest="Armor Health";
    private static final String HChest="Health";
    private static final String ABVChest="Absorb Value";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+HChest+" VARCHAR(255), "+ABVChest+" VARCHAR(255), "+AHChest+" VARCHAR(255));";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
    private Context context; 

    public ROGHelper (Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context=context;
        Message.message(context, "constructor called");
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // CREATE TABLE ARMORSTATS (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name VARCHAR(255));

        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            Message.message(context, "onCreate called");
        } catch (android.database.SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            Message.message(context, ""+e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVerison, int newVerison) {
        try {
            Message.message(context, "onUpgrade called");
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        } catch (android.database.SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Message.message(context, ""+e);
        }
    }
}
```

}

DamageTracker.java:

```
   package com.mikitz.rogsimple;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.EditText;

   public class DamageTracker extends Activity {

       EditText armorhealthchest, healthchest, abvchest;
   //   EditText headdi, armorhealthhead, healthheaad, abvhead;
   //   EditText rightarmdi, armorhealthrightarm, healthrightarm, abvrightarm; 
   //   EditText leftarmdi, armorhealthleftarm, healthleftarm, abvleftarm; 
   //   EditText rightlegdi, armorhealthrightleg, healthrightleg, abvrightleg; 
   //   EditText leftlegdi, armorhealthleftleg, healthleftleg, abvleftleg;
ROGDatabaseAdapter rogHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.damage_profile);

    armorhealthchest=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.armorhealthchest);
    healthchest=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.healthchest);
    abvchest=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.abvchest);

   //       headdi=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.headdi);
   //       rightarmdi=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.rightarmdi);
   //       leftarmdi=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.leftarmdi);
   //       rightlegdi=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.rightlegdi);
   //       leftlegdi=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.leftlegdi);

}

public void save(View view)
{
    String armorhealthcheststr=armorhealthchest.getText().toString(); 
    String healthcheststr=healthchest.getText().toString(); 
    String abvcheststr=abvchest.getText().toString(); 

    long id=rogHelper.insertData(armorhealthcheststr, healthcheststr, abvcheststr);
    if(id<0)
    {
        Message.message(this, "Unsuccesful");
    }
    else
    {
        Message.message(this, "Successfully inserted a row");

   //           Intent intent=new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
   //           startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `rogHelper` in `DamageTracker.java` is null at this line:

```
long id=rogHelper.insertData(armorhealthcheststr, healthcheststr, abvcheststr);
```

You need to initialize it first, preferably at `onCreate`.

Comment: Many thanks :) I can't believe I missed that.